# How to record-from-answer-dual with Twilio's object oriented interface?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I understand how to enable the 'record-from-answer-dual' with the XML style command set, but I'm not finding any way to accomplish the same thing with the more object-oriented style code, such as:

```
<?php
require_once 'twilio-php-master/Twilio/autoload.php';
$response = new Twilio\Twiml();

$sayMsg = 'Attention!  Attention!  The network operations 
center has opened a ticket concerning an ATMS failure in the Eastern 
region. The ticket number is ECHO,1,5,7,4.  I repeat, the ticket number is 
ECHO,1,5,7,4. Thank you.';

$response->record();
$response->say($sayMsg, array('voice' => 'alice'));
$response->hangup();
echo $response;
```

I've tried adding it to the `new` line, and the `record` line as an array-style entry, similar to enabling the Alice voice.  No dice.

I want to record the entire call, from answer, including the message spoken by Twilio.

Thanks for any information anyone can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

[`<Record>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record) is used to record messages from a call, not to record the TwiML that follows. It's more useful if you are building a messaging or voicemail system for voice.

Given that your message sounds like some kind of announcement, I am guessing that you are [generating this call from the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls). In that case, you can use the `Record` parameter when you place the call and the entire call will be recorded. In PHP, that would be something like this:

```
require_once '/path/to/vendor/autoload.php';
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
$sid = "your_account_sid";
$token = "your_auth_token";
$client = new Client($sid, $token);

$call = $client->calls->create(
    $to, $from,
    array(
        "url" => $url,
        "record" => true
    )
);
```

Check out [the documentation on the parameters you can use when making a call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/making-calls#optional-parameters), including `Record` here.

Let me know if that helps at all.

**Update from Jeffrey's comment**

This is the Perl version, using the unofficial Twilio Perl module:

```
use WWW::Twilio::API;
my ($twilaccountsid, $twilauthtoken, $fromnum, $tonum, $twiml_uri) = @_;
my $twilio = WWW::Twilio::API->new(AccountSid => $twilaccountsid, AuthToken => $twilauthtoken);
my $response = $twilio->POST( 'Calls', From => $fromnum, To => $tonum, Record => 'true', Url => $twiml_uri);
return $response->{content};
```

Comment: philnash, thank you very much for the information.  It appears to work well in php.  The new issue, which I failed to specify above mind you, is that I'm using Perl.  I use the WWW:Twilio::API module to initiate the outbound call via the Rest API. The code is very similar, but I'm not finding the syntax for adding the 'record' option anywhere.  Any recommendations?

Comment: Nevermind philnash.  I found it.  Thank you again.  Excellent answer.

Comment: For anyone else who finds this and needs it, here is the code:
    use WWW::Twilio::API;  
    my ($twilaccountsid, $twilauthtoken, $fromnum, $tonum, 
    $twiml_uri) = @_;

     my $twilio = WWW::Twilio::API->new(AccountSid => $twilaccountsid,
                                     AuthToken  => $twilauthtoken);

  my $response = $twilio->POST( 'Calls',
                             From => $fromnum,
                             To   => $tonum,
                             Record => 'true',
                             Url  => $twiml_uri);

  return $response->{content};

    }

Comment: Hey Jeffrey, thanks for the update. Added your Perl example to my answer.